# Tuning RocksDB performance in Spark Structured Streaming

Tags: apache-spark, caching, state, spark-structured-streaming, rocksdb

We are working on tuning RocksDB as a state store in Spark Structured Streaming. Going by the documentation of spark , we have limited options provided by Spark to tune certain settings like , enabling range compaction .

I want to play around with modifying

> mem table size and number of parallel mem tables hosted in memory

> write_buffer_size
>
> max_write_buffer_number
>
> min_write_buffer_number_to_merge

. But I dont see any handle for the same . Other tools like Flink, Kakfa streams have extensive options to tune RocksDB.

Any suggestions would help.
Should we modify any configuration file for RocksDB present in spark github project ?

Can we try to create a custom spark image with latest version of RocksDB ?

Answer (score 1):

Shared the question with the Speedb hive and this is what we got for you:

"from what I can tell, you can edit the sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/streaming/state/RocksDB.scala file and perform the modifications on the dbOptions object.
you can view the different options in the speedb/rocksdb repo under the java/rocksjni/options.cc file.
specifically regarding your question, you have:
setWriteBufferSize
setMaxWriteBufferNumber
setMinWriteBufferNumberToMerge

additionally, you can use setDbWriteBufferSize and setWriteBufferManager, which can be used to set up a total memory limit for several states (rocksdb dbs). note that this feature is quite lacking in the current rocksdb implementation and we are working on improving it (see https://github.com/speedb-io/speedb/issues/155 and https://github.com/speedb-io/speedb/issues/114). you can check the Kafka implementation for how it's being used to set the memory limit for several dbs."

Hope this helps. If you have follow-up questions or want further assistance, please join our hive on [Discord](https://discord.com/invite/5fVUUtM2cG) and we'll be happy to assist.

Comment: Sounds good .. let me try this approach . Thanks alot for the suggestion.

Comment: We were actually able to add these parameters and flow them through spark to rocksdb. Unfortunately , after increasing mem table size and number of buffers , we were not able to get memtable hit . In our case it's always 0.

Comment: Were you able to tune the RockDB's performance as state store? We are trying to use it as well and are facing memory bloats.